# Cross filter with a date not working

Tags: reporting, cross-filter

I'm trying to create a report showing me the accounts without contract for 2022 year

I selected :

- all accounts
- created date : all time
- Cross filter : accounts without contracts, start date less or equal 01/01/2022

But, this is giving me wrong results.
I should not have the 3 first lines with a start date, as it means there is a contract

Thanks for your support
[image]

[image]

Comment: Show report conditions as specified so we can check if conditions are specified correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-filters for without's can be confusing. I think you need to change your comparator to greater or equal to 1 Jan 2022, as you are looking for Accounts without Contacts where the start date is greater than that date.